# how to make FTP client frontend using windows 7 theme

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrqwi1e9ejlojam/win.jpg

As you can see in the image, in greenbox i am fetching localhost system files and functions.. which work perfectly.

but as you know FTP client has 2 modes, local and Remote site.

Now in red box you can see it blank, there i want to integrate windows 7 look like remote panel.. so once user login using his email and password and other required details.. he must see layout same as he see in green box.

I hope anyone can help me better here.

Comment: And... Where is question?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to show the tree level in remote site, right ?

If you're using .NETFramework, you can use system.net library, it's support for the protocol in FtpWebRequest, in the same way as HttpWebRequest supports web requests.

Here's the step for to do like a green box :

1. After providing user and pass, you make a command to list all parent directory and then you show it in tree panel.
2. after tree panel has been generated, you can make a command list for each click in tree panel to change directory from directory parent.
3. If there's file in current directory, you can show it using icon file in next panel.
4. next is up to you, what's going on after a file has been clicked, double clicked, or right click.

Comment: Ok sir, let me check and i will respond back asap!

Comment: sir, it don't have file browsing option etc.. please help.. :(

Comment: can you list your parent directory from your remote site ?
try to show list of directory to list box panel first, before using tree panel.

Comment: is there any dll, to fetch windows 7 layout in my application? any dll that i can manipulate and get this sorted quick.. as whole that setup will take a lot time.

Comment: if you want to mimic windows 7 layout, just do it like your green box.
apply the list of directory in remote site, just like you did in your green box, to customize the appearance.